# .lnk not showing up with get-childitem

Tags: windows, file, powershell, cmd, get-childitem

**OS: Windows 7 Pro SP 1
PowerShell-Version: 5.0.10514.6**

I use this command to list all of my startmenu shortcuts:

```
get-childitem "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\" -Recurse
```

The command return everything except the "Windows Media Center.lnk" which should be under "...\Start Menu\Programs"

The same thing happends if i use the dir command

I can see the file if i use file explorer so i know it exists!

Any idea on why it is not showing up?

Comment: Thanks for answering! I still get the same result when i use -Force...

Comment: also try `cmd /c dir /a` if it is still not there, the file may not actually be there. right click the shortcut and view the properties to see where it actually is.